# How to divide values in the same columns in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to divide values in a column by the values above and create a new column with the new values.
In my case I want to divide the value in column 1 by the value in column 0, how can I do that?

[image]

This is what I wrote (Just imported the data and selected the column I want to use)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('C:/Users/aleja/Downloads/^GSPC.csv')
a=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Adj Close'])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the shift operation is the operation you are looking for:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

```
a["new_column"] = a["Adj close"].shift(1)/a["Adj close"]
```